# g++ doesn't find file despite correct path

Tags: linux, qt, gcc, qtgui

I downloaded source of qt 5.1.1 and successfully built it. Now I'm trying to test it and set the correct paths variables. I got all include files in /usr/local/qt511/include and libs in /usr/.../lib , and when I'm trying to build it with g++ with this cmd:

```
g++ -Wall -I/usr/local/qt511/include main.cpp -o main
```

it throws error. 
I noticed that in qt511 in include dir there are additional dirs with headers. So my first question Do this option `-I/usr/local/qt511/include` is sufficient to notify compiler about all headers despite their allocation in child directories?

Moreover I tried to build an example from tutorial. Very simple. F.e analogclock. It has in its body #include < QtGui >.
 So I tried to compile it with such cmd:

```
g++ -Wall -I/usr/local/qt511/include/QtGui main.cpp -o main
```

and the responce is:

```
In file included from main.cpp:41:0:
/usr/local/qt511/include/QtGui/QtGui:3:30 fatal error : QtGui/QtGuiDepends : No such file or directory. Compilation Terminated.
```

I checked the QtGui directory and there is QtGuiDepends....
I have no clue what is going on

thx in advance for any hint

Answer (score 0):

After some long evenings....

Ok I have found answers in these topics:
[Bash: Recursively adding subdirectories to the path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657108/bash-recursively-adding-subdirectories-to-the-path)
**and**
[How to make g++ search for header files in a specific directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12654013/how-to-make-g-search-for-header-files-in-a-specific-directory)

What I did to solve my problem is:
add to my .bashrc ( I use Ubuntu 12.04)
`export  CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH=/pathtoincludedir` with this nice trick in first link I added.
Now I can compile my qt programs simply with
`g++ -Wall main.cpp -o filename`

Hope this will help other beginners like me =) Never stop digging !