# Recursively adding bash scripts as commands in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, command

I'm pretty new to Bash and Linux in general. I've created a couple scripts that I would like to be able to use by typing the command, rather than the directory and the executable file. I'm using Debian Jessie if that makes a difference.

The path to one of my scripts is `~/Scripts/DIR_1/My_Script.sh` while another is in `~Scripts/DIR_2/My_Other_Script.sh`. I would like ALL of the scripts contained withing the `Scripts` directory to be indexed as commands regardless of directory/path depth.

I've appended this text to the end of my `.bashrc` file...

`PATH=${PATH}:$(find ~/Scripts -type d | sed '/\/\\./d' | tr '\n' ':' | sed 's/:$//')`

Since I'm pretty new to this kind of thing, I had to steal that line from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657108/bash-recursively-adding-subdirectories-to-the-path).

When I try to run `My_Script` from the command line withing a sub directory of my home folder (or anywhere else for that matter) I get `My_Script: command not found`

I will readily admit that I might have misunderstood the process of adding a bash script to the command line.

How do I recursively add bash scripts as commands? What is wrong with the process I'm currently using?

Comment: ln -s /path/to/script /usr/local/bin (or /usr/bin). Best option: put all your scripts in one folder (e.g /opt/script) and this folder to your PATH

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your issue is that you're not putting the .sh, that is part of your file name.

Normally, pressing tab after having typed only the first letter should complete the command up to the point where there is an ambiguity (or completely if there's none). In case of ambiguity, pressing tab a second time shows the options. So in your case, if you type `My<tab><tab>` you should have options `My_Script.sh` and `My_Other_Script.sh` displayed. And if you type `My_Script<tab>` it should complete by putting `My_Script.sh`

**Edit**

I forgot to precise that you can check the value of PATH by doing `echo $PATH`. This will allow you to check that the command you copied did what you wanted.

Comment: The other problem I had was that I guess the system requires a reboot to index the changes to .bashrc. Is there a way that I can add the command so that I don't have to append .sh?

Comment: The system doesn't need to reboot but you need either to relaunch bash (by opening a new terminal or relogging) or to source your .bashrc (with `source .bashrc`).

To not have to put the .sh, you can create an alias without the .sh (in your .bashrc: `alias My_Script=My_Script.sh`) but you will have to do it for each command (you can generate it with a similar `find` command) or to not put the .sh in your file. This second option is my preferred one. The extension is not necessary at all for the system to determine the type of file so simply drop it !

Comment: Hmm. The terminal is telling me that it doesn't know what the "source" command is.

Comment: Strange, are you sure you are in the same terminal, with the same user ? `echo $PATH` can help you diagnose. Using <tab> for the completion too.

Instead of source, you can also simply type `. ~/.bashrc` that has the same effect.

Comment: Thanks for all that info. I really appreciate it. I realized why the command was only working sometimes. It seems "sudo" doesn't find my command, but running the command without "sudo" works perfectly. What is going on here?

Comment: The first half of my answer was concerning the part of the comment you removed :-)

Comment: sudo is running command with root user, so using root's shell configuration, not the one of your user. Therefore sudo cannot see the commands that are in the directories you added in your PATH.

Comment: Ahh. How does one adjust the root's PATH? Will affecting the root user trickle down to all other user accounts? Some of the commands in some of my scripts will definitely require execution as root.

Comment: The same way as for your user: by modifying /root/.bashrc. This will not affect other users, only root. The common configuration for all users is in /etc/bash.bashrc (at least on my distribution). Another option for your script is to use an explicit path when it needs to call another script. You can retrieve current path of the script with `dirname $0`. It's more robust because it doesn't force user to have the directories in their PATH, they can call the script with the full path. A great tutorial: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/