# How to add subfolders into path on windows?

Tags: windows, automation, path

I want to add folders to PATH like this
C:/MyFiles/*
Or for example

- C:/MyFiles/Folder1
- C:/MyFiles/Folder2
- C:/MyFiles/Folder3
- C:/MyFiles/Folder4

Thanks

Comment: Just add C:\MyFiles\;

Comment: @LarryB not working in windows 10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No way to do that. Only possible solution is add folder by folder.

Answer (score 0):

Open advanced system settings. Click environment variables, scroll to Path under system variables or user variables, then click edit and add C:\MyFiles\YourFiles

EDIT:

https://superuser.com/questions/569466/add-a-directory-and-all-subdirectories-to-the-path-variable-with-a-single-entry

[How to recursively add subdirectories to the PATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/657108/how-to-recursively-add-subdirectories-to-the-path)

Comment: This add only current folder, i need to add recursively subfolders too

Comment: Path mechanisms usually do not walk through sub-directories by design. If you want to use the content of those sub-folders, I suggest simply moving them into one folder. Or, I could have misunderstood you and all you need to do is remove "YourFiles" from my answer. If not, i've included some links that should be able to help you more

Comment: I read first link, maybe i dont understand smth, but there there's no way to add subfolders in win to path

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me on Windows 10, VS Code, when Python installed .exe files to a folder and recommended to add folder to Path:

key strokes Windows + x, then y > About > Advanced system settings > Advanced > Environmental Variables > from pane "User variables for <your_user_name>" highlight Path > Edit > New > paste the folder's path > OK > OK